# Mongoose findOne works with "_id" fails with "username"

Tags: mongoose

User model:

```js
var User = new Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String
})
```

There is a user with the username "six".

In mongo shell this works:

```js
db.users.findOne({username:'six'})
```

With mongoose this works:

```js
User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, user) {
  res.json(user)
})
```

But this doesn't:

```js
User.findOne({username:'six'}, function(err, user) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
  res.json(user);
});
```

There is no error returned but no user either. I am missing something and I can't see what.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `username` in single quotes, like so:

```
User.findOne({'username':'six'}, function(err, user) {
   if(err) console.log(err);
   res.json(user);
});
```

Comment: No difference still not working for some reason. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Arg okay. Could you try setting "six" as a variable in the line above the query, and using that? Just as a sanity check

Comment: I used User.findOne({'username':req.params.username}, which I checked by console.logging to make sure it had the value 'six'. No change however.

Comment: Can you try adding a console.log inside the callback for "user" (if you haven't already)?

Comment: I have tried adding console.log in the callback but the function doesn't fire. Nothing happens - no errors just nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the working `User.findOne({_id: req.params.id}` which was in a `router.get('/:id',)` immediately before the non-working `User.findOne({'username':'six'}` which was in a `router.get('/:username')` and it started working.

So I could not have 2 router.get('/:XXX') - even though they were different paths `- /:id` and `/:username`

I thought that express route handlers allow multiple routes for a path and that there could be problems if, say both were router.get('/:id) then the second one never gets called (which was happening to my /:username route) as the first route ends the request-response cycle. But I mistakenly thought as the paths were different that would not apply.
My apologies to @Lucas Watson for not making the whole code available as I'm sure he would have spotted my mistake.

As an alternative I could have added:

```
if (req.params.id == 0) next('route');
```

to the /:id route callback.

Comment: Those are _not_ different paths, you're just assigning a differently named parameter to them. They still match the same.